# Why does my HOC NotEmpty not work when access property?

Tags: reactjs

Here is a simple HOC NotEmpty:

```
const NotEmpty = ({value,children}) =>{
    return (value ? children : null);
};
```

The purpose of this HOC is to prevent the children from being displayed when the value is null or undefined
So, this will work

```
<NotEmpty value={thread}>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</NotEmpty>
```

But not this:

```
<NotEmpty value={thread}>
    <p>{thread.title}</p>
</NotEmpty>

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

So what is wrong with my NotEmpty HOC and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what is wrong with my NotEmpty HOC and how to fix it?

You accept `children` directly, so they should be computed before calling `NotEmpty` and that computation produces the error. You can pass lambda that produces content instead and delay the computation:

```
const NotEmpty = ({condition, render}) =>{
  return (condition ? render() : null);
};
```

And use it like:

```
<NotEmpty 
   condition={thread} 
   render={() => <p>{thread.title}</p>}/>
```

You can also pass lambda for rendering through `children` as:

```
<NotEmpty condition={thread}>
   {() => <p>{thread.title}</p>}
</NotEmpty>
```

Answer (score 0):

That problem is not your HOC. Problem is `thread` may be thread doen't has property `title`. I already test here
https://codesandbox.io/s/w0q8l59ykl .You can change this to prevent error

```
<NotEmpty value={thread}>
  <p>{thread && thread.title}</p>
</NotEmpty>
```

Comment: It will work only when thread already defined, but when the value is null or undefined, it won't work which is against the whole purpose of my HOC

Comment: The whole purpose of this NotEmpty is so I don't need to add check like this.